# Counting Bars Ago since peak

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am writing an algorithm to count the number of bars have passed since the n-th peak.
Assuming that I have a list of integer which keeps track of all the occurrences of peak as below.

> `3`, `7`, `10`, `13`
>
> The above tells me that the peak occurs at the index  `3`, `7`, `10` and `13`.
>   The length of the source data is `15`.

### Let `n = 1`

then I should be seeing a resultant list as below:

- `index 0 = null` - there is no peak yet
- `index 1 = null` - there is no peak yet
- `index 2 = null` - there is no peak yet
- `index 3 = 0` - peak was hit here so there bars passed is 0
- `index 4 = 1` - peak was hit in previous bar so the bars passed is 1
- `index 5 = 2` - peak was already hit and the number of bars passed is 2
- `index 6 = 3`  - peak was already hit and the number of bars passed is 3
- `index 7 = 0` - peak hit here again so the number of bars passed since the last 1 (n) peak is 0 and result follows as below:

  `index 8 = 1`,
  `index 9 = 2`,
  `index 10 = 0`,
  `index 11 = 1`,
  `index 12 = 2`,
  `index 13 = 0`,
  `index 14 = 1`

### Assume `n = 2`

number of bars passed since 2 most recent peaks. So the result is as below:

- `index 0 = null`
- `index 1 = null`
- `index 2 = null`
- `index 3 = null` - first peak but `n = 2` so there is no 2nd peak so far...
- `index 4 = null`
- `index 5 = null`
- `index 6 = null`
- `index 7 = 4` - second peak only hit here, so the number of days passed since the last 2 peak is 4, this is counted from the index where the first peak was hit, in this case is 3
- `index 8 = 5`
- `index 9 = 6`
- `index 10 = 3` - another peak hit here, the peak before *this (`n = 2`)* happened at `index  = 7`, so it is counted from `index = 7`
- `index 11 = 4`
- `index 12 = 5`
- `index 13 = 3` - another peak hit here, the peak before *this (`n = 2`)* happened at `index = 10`, so it is counted from `index = 10`
- `index 14 = 4`

I wrote an algorithm to accomplish this however, it's not giving me the right output. I would appreciate if someone could tell me what's wrong with my algo or propose a better way doing this.

```
    int nth =  GetNValue();// Get the N Value...
    //SourceData = listData
    int peakCount = 0;
    int value= 0; 
    int barssince = 0;
    List<Data> listValue = new List<Data>();
    List<int> listResult =  new List<int); //to hold the result..
    List<int> listPeaks = GetPeakValue();
    for (int index = 0; index < listData.Count; index++)
    {
     if (peakcount > 0)
     {
           barssince++;
           listValue[listValue.Count - 1].Value = barssince;
     }
     int foundPeak = listPeaks.Find(delegate(int p) { return p == index; });
     if (foundPeak != -1)//Peak FOund
     {
         peakcount++;
         listValue.Add(new Data() { Value = barssince });
         if (peakcount > nth)
         {
               listValue.RemoveAt(0);
         }
         barssince = 0;
     }
     value = listValue.Count >= nth ? listValue.Sum(p => p.Value) : null;
     listResult.Add(value);
    }
    private class Data
    {
       public int Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Use stack to find peaks and store them in a list. You can probably use some sort of binary search to speed up number of bars passed for a given index `i`. If you want to find for the whole array, then it can be done in `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int n =  GetNValue();// Get the N Value...   
List<int> listPeaks = GetPeakValue(); 
List<int?> result = new List<int?>(listData.Count);
for (int index = 0, peakIndex = -1, nextPeakIndex = peakIndex + n; index < listData.Count; index++)
{
    if (nextPeakIndex < listPeaks.Length && index == listPeaks[nextPeakIndex])
    {
        peakIndex++;
        nextPeakIndex++;
    }

    if (peakIndex < 0)
    {
        result.Add((int?)null);
    }
    else
    {
        result.Add((int?)(index - listPeaks[peakIndex]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple algo with working code (sorry, but in Delphi):

```
function IsPeak(i: Integer): Boolean;//modelling
begin
  Result := i in [3, 7, 10, 13, 15];
end;

var
  i, N: Integer;
  Q: TQueue<Integer>;
begin
  N := 2;

  //queue for last N peaks
  Q := TQueue<Integer>.Create;
  for i := 0 to 20 do begin

    //insert new peak in queue
    if IsPeak(i) then begin
      Q.Enqueue(i);
      //remove too old peak
      if Q.Count > N then
        Q.Dequeue;
     end;

    if Q.Count < N then 
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('%d null',[i]))
    else  //return difference with front element of the queue
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('%d %d',[i, i - Q.Peek]))
  end;
  Q.Free;

Result:

0 null
1 null
2 null
3 null
4 null
5 null
6 null
7 4
8 5
9 6
10 3
11 4
12 5
13 3
14 4
15 2
16 3
17 4
18 5
19 6
20 7
```